# missing closing div tag

Tags: html, css

I have a website which is composed of Master page and a ascx that fits into it.
Unfortenatly I see the page doesn't look the way I expect it to.

After a short investigation I figured out it can be a missing closing div tag in my ascx. 
The problem is that the code is very very long.

Is there any automated  online tool that can show me places in code that can lead to this? Meaning places with missing div tag?

any other creative idea would be helpful as well

Comment: Did you try using opening the generated HTML in Visual Studio or  notepad++? They both provide a easy way of navigating the tags.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the code in Notepad ++ or other editor with color highlighting, save it as html and click on tags to see which one doesn't have a closing tag? Or there are really that many divs?

Comment: Might sound silly but you could just try adding a closing div after the last closing div. You'd be surprised how many times that's worked for me.

Comment: If you indent your code in a text editor, it becomes apparent where the closing `</div>` should be. Otherwise, I second @Jamie Dixon's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org/ or you can install (if you are using Firefox) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/