# Link closing tags missing

Tags: html, regex

I think I botched a search and replace operation and wound up with quite a few instances where my links don't have closing tags. They include text links...

```
<a href="/World/Venezuela" title="Venezuela">Venezuela</a>
```

images...

```
<a href="/World/Venezuela" title="Venezuela"><img></a>
```

and both...

```
<a href="/World/Venezuela" title="Venezuela"><img>
(Click to see a bigger picture)</a>
```

I would like to find a tool to help me locate all the links that need to be fixed - all links without closing tags. Does anyone know of a script, regex or software program that can do this?

I'm working mostly with Dreamweaver, TextWrangler and TextEdit on a Mac.

**Note:** *I found some good basic tips @ [missing closing div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205919/missing-closing-div-tag). However, I have literally thousands of files to search through and don't have time to validate each or visually inspect the code, nor can I use Notepad on a Mac.*

Comment: I hope this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307178/any-tools-to-find-missing-html-tags

Comment: Yeah You can go for the accepted answer or the textmate option as you are on working on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it looks like all of these solutions require you to examine one file at a time. I'd like to find some sort of tool or regex that can analyze a folder containing a thousand files and identify every file that has a missing tag. Dreamweaver's search and replace operations do something similar, except I don't know how to search for a missing tag with Dreamweaver.

Comment: this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814182/find-closing-html-tag-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 0):

Try with SublimeText, I use it in mi Mac.

Comment: I haven't yet verified that Sublime Text can find missing tags, but that looks like a great software program. I'm going to buy it tomorrow!

Comment: You don't have to buy it, there is a free version, that is what I use.